# I am getting a 'Cannot set property 'variable' of undefined' in the following component

Tags: angular

The component will render a list of values fetched from an API. I am getting the following component initialization issue:

```
Cannot set property 'hits' of undefined
```

display-recipes.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { SearchRecipeService } from '../search-recipe.service';
import { RecipeGlobal } from '../pojos/RecipeGlobal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-recipes',
  templateUrl: './display-recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-recipes.component.css']
})
export class DisplayRecipesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() calories: String;
  @Input() recipe: String;
  recipeResult: RecipeGlobal;
  constructor(private searchRecipeService: SearchRecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.recipeResult.hits = [];
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.getRecipeInfo();
  }

  getRecipeInfo(){
     this.searchRecipeService.getRecipeInfo().
     subscribe(recipeResult => this.recipeResult = recipeResult);
  }

}
```

display-recipes.component.html

```
<p>display-recipes works!</p>
<div id='display_recipe'  *ngFor="let recipe of recipeResult.hits">
    {{recipe.label}}
</div>
```

RecipeGlobal.ts

```
export class RecipeGlobal{
    q: String;
    hits: Recipe[];
}

export class Recipe{
    image: String;
    calories: String;
    label: String
}
```

I am failing to understand how objects are initialized in typescript. If I declare a non primitive inside the object, do I have to initialize it?. If so, in this case how should I initialize the array?.

Answer (score 0):

You must start your variable on declaration. `recipeResult: RecipeGlobal = {};`. When you are starting the array in `ngOnInit`, the variable is `undefined`. so `this.recipeResult.hits` generates a null pointer.

For that you need to put all attributes as optionals:

```
export class RecipeGlobal{
    q?: String;
    hits?: Recipe[];
}
```

Or you don't initialize the variable, then in your ngFor you must use safe navigation operator `?`.

```
<p>display-recipes works!</p>
<div id='display_recipe'  *ngFor="let recipe of recipeResult?.hits">
    {{recipe.label}}
</div>
```

Comment: Should I also initialize the non-primitives inside the object in ngoninit?

Comment: I think you actualy don't need to iniatialize anything. But your error is being thrown by the non initialized variable. Do you get any errors when you don't initialize and use the safe navigation operator?

Comment: Now I am getting Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RecipeGlobal': q, hits.. I shouldn't populate this object upon initialization.

Comment: You must put all attributes as optional: `q?: String;` `hits?: Recipe[];`. But I recommend trying not to initialize variable and combine it with safe navigation operator

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new instance of `RecipeGlobal`

```
 recipeResult: RecipeGlobal = new RecipeGlobal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occuring because of this line of code

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.recipeResult.hits = [];
  }
```

Since **recipeResult** variable is not **defined** yet.

The **ngOnInit** lifecycle hook would get called before the data is fetched from the api.

Now you'll have to define the **recipeResult** variable before hand, e.g. where it was declared, change that line to this

```
recipeResult: RecipeGlobal = new RecipeGlobal();
```

Thanks.